# ¿Cómo hago que un array que tengo en un storage sea reactivo?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web

estoy intentando hacer un array reactivo en Vue usando Pinia.
Tengo el siguiente storage:

```
import { ref, computed } from 'vue'
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const listRoom = defineStore('room', () => {
  const rooms = ref([])
  return { rooms }
})
```

En el storage tengo un array 'rooms' y en mi componente invoco el storage de esta forma:

```
import { listRoom } from "../stores/room";
const storageRooms = listRoom()
```

y accedo a rooms de esta forma `storageRooms.rooms`
De tal manera que cuando imprimo el array sólo me imprime el último elemento que añado, ya que no es reactivo.He oido que puedo hacerlo con un computed, pero no sé de que manera.

Dejo mi código por si le echan un vistazo:

```
<template>
  <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center h-screen p-10">
    <form @submit.prevent="createRoom">
      Name:<input type="text" v-model="nameRoom">
      Description:<input type="text" v-model="descriptionRoom">
      <button type="submit">Create</button>
    </form>
    <Room v-for="room in storageRooms.rooms" :key="room.id"
         :id="room.id" 
         :Name="room.Name" 
         :Description="room.Description" 
         :devices="room.Devices"
         @roomDeleted="deleteRooms"
         @deviceDeleted="deleteDevice"
         >
    </Room>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from "vue"
import Room from "../components/Room.vue"
import { listRoom } from "../stores/room";

import {
  giveCollection,
  borraDoc,
  anadir
} from "@/API/firebase"

const storageRooms = listRoom()
const nameRoom = ref("")
const descriptionRoom = ref("")

onMounted(() => {
    loadRoomsAndDevices()
})

const createRoom=async()=>{
  console.log('create room')
  const newRoom = {
    Name: nameRoom.value,
    Description: descriptionRoom.value,
  }
  await anadir("Rooms",newRoom)
}

const loadRoomsAndDevices = async (DeviceType) => {
  await giveCollection("Rooms", (querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      const room = {
        id: doc.id,
        Name: doc.data().Name,
        Description: doc.data().Description,
        Devices: []
      }
      // Buscar si la sala ya existe en el array
      const index = storageRooms.rooms.findIndex((room) => room.id === room.id);
      if (index === -1) {
        storageRooms.rooms.push(room);
      }
    })
  })
  await giveCollection("Devices", (querySnapshot) => {
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    const device = {
      id: doc.id,
      Name: doc.data().Name,
      Value: doc.data().Value,
      Type: doc.data().Type,
      Room: doc.data().Room
    }
    storageRooms.rooms.forEach((room) => {
      if (room.Name === device.Room) {
        // Buscar si el dispositivo ya existe en el array de dispositivos de la sala
        const index = room.Devices.findIndex((d) => d.id === device.id);
        if (index === -1) {
          // El dispositivo no existe, agregarlo al array
          room.Devices.push(device);
        } else {
          // El dispositivo ya existe, actualizar su información
          room.Devices[index] = device;
        }
      }
    })
  })
})
}

const deleteRooms = async (roomId) => {
  // Borrar la sala de la base de datos
  await borraDoc("Rooms", roomId);

  // Filtrar la lista de salas para quitar la sala que acabas de borrar
  const newRooms = storageRooms.rooms.filter((room) => room.id !== roomId);

  // Actualizar el valor de rooms con el nuevo array filtrado
  storageRooms.rooms = newRooms;
}

const deleteDevice = async (deviceId) => {
  // Recorrer la lista de habitaciones para encontrar la habitación que contiene el dispositivo
  for (let i = 0; i < storageRooms.rooms.length; i++) {
    const room = storageRooms.rooms[i];
    const index = room.Devices.findIndex((device) => device.id !== deviceId);
    if (index === -1) {
      // Si se encuentra el dispositivo, borrarlo de la lista de dispositivos de la habitación
      room.Devices.splice(index, 1);
      // Borrar el dispositivo de la base de datos
      await borraDoc("Devices", deviceId);
      // Salir del bucle una vez que se ha encontrado y eliminado el dispositivo
      break;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Su pregunta viene a ser por qué en la función `loadRoomsAndDevices()` -> `storageRooms.rooms.push(room);` no hay reactividad al mutar `rooms` desde el componente ? que es lo que trata de explicar acá: " De tal manera que cuando imprimo el array sólo me imprime el último elemento que añado..."

Comment: Al final lo resolví poniendo que si está la sala no se añada de nuevo

Comment: Sigo teniendo errores con ello

Comment: Tiene que ver con esta pregunta? si lo es, puede responder a mi comentario para ordenar el problema y responder al punto